# How to sync timer with server on iOS

Tags: objective-c, swift, nstimer

I am building a TOTP app for which it is important to sync a timer up to the second with a server. Every 30 seconds I want to generate a new One Time Password. Is there a way to trigger a timer based on `TimeIntervalSince1970` that I am not seeing? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at [RFC 6238](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238)? Right now, your question is too broad, can you pinpoint the specific problem you're dealing with?

Comment: I have, the algorithm is working. What I am looking now for is a way to trigger a timer every 30 seconds to both show a new token and start an animation for every time slice.

Comment: Something like `let timer = NSTimer(fireDate: NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: 0), interval: 30, target: self, selector: Selector("newToken"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)` However, this is not working.

Comment: why don't use the basic `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:` ?

Comment: Because if you use that you start counting from the moment the view appears. I want any device using the timer to be exactly in sync.

Answer (score 0):

This is *pretty* late, but maybe this will help people in the future:

I wrote a full TOTP implementation in Swift 3, which you can find [here](https://github.com/danielVebman/Totp-Token/blob/master/DigitCode.swift). It syncs very closely to, but just after, the true time. Assuming that the two parties (device and server) are synced with the true (or at least the same) time, we can also sync the timer to change every 30 seconds when the token changes. Here are two functions to do this:

```
/// Syncs and then starts the timer to be just behind the true 30 second time cycle.
private func syncTimer() {
    if totpToken != nil { delegate?.totpTokenDidChange(code: totpToken!) }
    let wait = 30 - (Date().timeIntervalSince1970).truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 30) + 0.5
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: wait, repeats: false) { (_) in
        self.startTimer()
    }
}

/// Starts the timer for calling `delegate` method `totpTokenDidChange(code:)` every 30 seconds.
private func startTimer() {
    if totpToken != nil { delegate?.totpTokenDidChange(code: totpToken!) }
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true) { (_) in
        if self.totpToken != nil { self.delegate?.totpTokenDidChange(code: self.totpToken!) }
    }
}
```

This is part of a full class that I wrote (linked to above) that manages all of this for you in the background.